# prove that $\exists \mathbb{R}\ni\lambda \ne 0$ such that $S = \lambda T$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $\boldsymbol{S}$ and $\boldsymbol{T}$ two non-zero symmetric $(0,2)$ tensors in finite dimensional vector space $\mathcal{V}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, and $\boldsymbol{S}, \boldsymbol{T}$ satisfy
$$
\boldsymbol{T} \otimes \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b},\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{d}) - \boldsymbol{T} \otimes \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{b},\boldsymbol{c}) + \boldsymbol{T} \otimes \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{b},\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{d}) - \boldsymbol{T} \otimes \boldsymbol{S}(\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{d},\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b}) \equiv 0
$$
with $\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b},\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{d} \in \mathcal{V}$. Prove $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \lambda \ne 0$ such that
$$
\boldsymbol{T} = \lambda \boldsymbol{S}
$$
Here, we use definition of tensor as multilinear map as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multilinear_maps); tensor product is defined as: $\boldsymbol{S} \otimes \boldsymbol{T}(<input~of~S>,<input~of~T>):= \boldsymbol{S}(<input~of~S>).\boldsymbol{T}(<input~of~T>)$; and symmetric means permutation of input give same output.

I try use some special input like permutation of $(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b},\boldsymbol{c},\boldsymbol{d})$, or $(\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b},\boldsymbol{a},\boldsymbol{b})$, or use $\boldsymbol{e}_i$, with hope to cancel out some term to get result, but not work.

**Answer:** the answer is in the comments of user10354138

Comment: Picking $c=b,d=a$, we have by symmetry of $S,T$ and the given condition, that $T(a,a)S(b,b)=T(b,b)S(a,a)$ for all $a,b$. So $T=\lambda S$ follows.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you give more detail? From this equality,  I just see that $\frac{T(a,a)}{S(a,a)} = \text{const} = \lambda, \forall a$, so have $T(\boldsymbol{e}_i,\boldsymbol{e}_i) = \lambda S(\boldsymbol{e}_i,\boldsymbol{e}_i)$. How to prove that $T(\boldsymbol{e}_i,\boldsymbol{e}_j) = \lambda S(\boldsymbol{e}_i,\boldsymbol{e}_j)$ for $i\ne j$.

Comment: Polarisation identity.